# Creating an empty VBox in FXML and later adding nodes in javafx doesn't work

Tags: javafx, fxml

In my FXML i have a simple empty VBox inside an AnchorPane:

```
<VBox fx:id="clients" spacing="10" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="150.0">
        <children>
        </children>
</VBox>
```

Then I want to add a node to the VBox in java class:

```
clients.getChildren().add(0, customObject.getGridPane());
```

But the node doesn't show up, VBox keeps empty.

If I simply add any node to the FXML then later adding a node in java works but not if it starts empty.

This works:

```
<VBox fx:id="clients" spacing="10" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="150.0">
        <children>
            <Label />
        </children>
</VBox>
```

It must be an easy thing I'm missing but couldn't find the answer anywhere.

Comment: Where do you call the `add` function ? and have you tried to add a simple object like `Label` instead of `getGridPane` ?

Comment: I tried adding a `new Label("Test")` but doesn't work either. I'm calling the `add` from the parent AnchorPane controller.

Comment: Why use the FXML at all if you're only going to populate it with code later anyway?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem

Comment: I wont spend a lot of time creating a whole verifiable example which would include the using of not popular libraries to achieve specific needs. I was looking for someone experiencied who could easily say.. "oh.. yeah.. in some situations that happens, try the following.." if there isn't any then I would simply take an other aproach and thats it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use addAll  method instead of add

```
clients.getChildren().addAll(0, customObject.getGridPane());
```

Comment: add is just for one node

Comment: I don't believe thats the reason since `add` didn't even worked with a simple `Label` or `Button` but those worked using `addAll`, same with the GridPane I was trying to add. But I'm glad it worked.

Comment: yes , the first value is an int . please uncheck this answer

Comment: I realized it was wrong.. still `addAll` was what solved my problem and this answer gave me the idea

Answer (score 0):

I tried it and it's working fine the problem is in this code `customObject.getGridPane()` make sure that it get a node I added a `Button` and it's working fine
***Note:*** *label didn't show because of text color try a button*

Comment: It's not the case. I will edit question with more context.